# Unit testing with Expressions?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, expression

I am unit testing some code that interactes with a repository, that takes an expression (`Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>`) to filter the results, like so:

```
int orderId = 10;

_respository.GetFiltered(order => order.Id == orderId);
```

I am having a problem Unit Testing, more specifically setting up expectations that an expression will match.  In a unit test I want to do this:

```
_mockRespository.Setup(r => r.GetFiltered(order => order.Id == 10)).Returns(new Order[0]).AtMostOnce();
```

I found one solution that suggested doing `.ToString()` on each expression and compairing that, however when you reference a variable such as orderId, the expression is completely different!

What are people doing to test this?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Not sure i understand... instead of passing expressions to the Setup method. What if you cache it in a local var and pass that to the setup method.

Comment: If you do that, then the same question remains!  How do I compare that two expressions are the same!?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is in part a matter of what you actually want to verify with a unit test, which comes down to your unit testing philosophy.

What we do is we don't necessarily verify that a linq to entities expression parameter passed from type A (under test) uses a specific expression tree when calling GetFoo() on a repository collaborator (not under test). For a unit test, we are content with verifying that method GetFoo() the correct signature is called at all.

In your case it looks like you are using Moq (?), in which case that would become something like this (beware of syntax mess)

```
_mockRespository.Setup(r => r.GetFiltered(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>())).Returns(new Order[0]).AtMostOnce();
```

For us, this makes sense because a) mocked method parameter expression tree comparison verification is indeed a pain and b) even if we could verify that parameter, how B actually would interpret different combinations of parameter values might change (as in semantics of contract A->B) and if that's the case, would make the test brittle.

We use automated story tests for testing interaction between production A and production B. We think this is a better way to test these scenarios, since they are typically something like 'filter all A in storage according to expression X and give me all the objects that match'. For us, this makes sense as integration tests (one or two happy cases usually are enough).

If that's not enough for you, I'd read up on a) how to create custom Moq matchers, though I can't say for certain that there is an easy solution (there might very well be) or b) setting up expectation callbacks so you can capture the parameter and inspect it after the test. Something like this:

```
    Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> actualExpression = null;
    _mockRespository.Setup(r => r.GetFiltered(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>())).Returns(new Order[0]).AtMostOnce().Callback((Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> expr => { actualExpression = expr});

    // exercise production code

    Assert.IsTrue(actualExpression ...... someithing clever here);
```

Note: All above code was written in the stack overflow editor. Don't hold me accountable if it does not compile, the Moq docs cover this